# User Defined Runtime Attributes With Swift Int Type (without NSNumber)

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a several generic views in a Storyboard that use the same class. The class relies on an enumerated value to determine what content to show. I am setting this property in Interface Builder's User Defined Runtime Attributes:

```
var rawAppSectionIndex: NSNumber?
```

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes in IB]

Then in the view did load I convert the raw value to the enumerated type:

```
let appSectionIndex = AppSectionIndex(rawValue: Int(rawAppSectionIndex))
```

This works when `rawAppSectionIndex` is a type of NSNumber, but it doesn't work for a Swift Int. Am I missing something or are Swift types not yet supported by Interface Builder's User Defined Runtime Attributes?

Comment: You should mark your property as `@IBInspectable` then you can edit it from the attributes inspector instead of manually setting the runtime attributes

Comment: I've never used `@IBInspectable`, yet I had read about it, so thanks for the reminder! I've now implemented this and it obviously works with the Swift Int type. Feel free to submit this solution as an answer if you like.